# how to set AlternateId for an asset in azure media service?

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

I am trying to add some custom metadata to every video stored in azure media service. As part of this I am trying to change the value of **AlternateId** of an asset stored in Azure media service.

I could see that the key is available as part of `IAsset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the CloudMediaContext to Create or Encode an asset you are handed the asset back. At this point you can set the AlternateId and call Update.

```
      IAsset inputAsset = _mediaContext.Assets.CreateFromBlob(blob, 
                            storageCredentials, AssetCreationOptions.None);

      inputAsset.AlternateId = assetId.ToString();
      inputAsset.Update();
```